# "Qualidade muito baixa" é para lixo

Tags: debate, sinalização, qualidade

Tem um tipo de sinalização no site chamado de "qualidade muito baixa". A descrição diz:

> **qualidade muito baixa**
>   Esta [pergunta/resposta] tem graves problemas de formatação ou conteúdo. É improvável que esta [pergunta/resposta] seja recuperável por meio de edição e talvez seja necessário removê-la.

O espírito dessa sinalização está na segunda frase:

> **É improvável que** esta [pergunta/resposta] **seja recuperável por meio de edição e talvez seja necessário removê-la.**

Acontece que essa frase perde a força perto da expressão "qualidade muito baixa" e da primeira frase da descrição, que são bastante amplas e, pior, subjetivas. Assim, muitos acabam sinalizando conteúdos que não precisam ser excluídos, apenas editados ou negativados.

Quando essas sinalizações chegam aos moderadores, várias acabam rejeitadas por não se tratarem de casos para exclusão. Outras acabam marcadas como úteis mesmo sem a exclusão da postagem, mas nesse caso a sinalização acarreta um [voto negativo automático do sistema](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281805/does-community-downvote-vlq-posts). Eu não gosto muito desse negativo automático. Mesmo quando é caso para negativo, eu preferiria que o próprio usuário que sinalizou tivesse negativado em vez de sinalizado. E esse mecanismo acaba pesando no trabalho dos moderadores, que acabam tendo que dar a palavra final sobre uma negativação.

Esta discussão é para saber o que vocês acham disso. Eu particularmente acho que essa sinalização poderia ser extinta ou no mínimo repensada e renomeada. Existem algumas discussões no meta geral da rede nesse sentido. Também é para pedir que pensem duas vezes antes de sinalizar como "qualidade muito baixa", principalmente em respostas. Se não for caso para conversão em comentário ou não-resposta – que têm sinalizações específicas –, pense bem se é caso para exclusão. Se achar que sim ou tiver uma dúvida razoável, sinalize. Senão, pode ser caso para edição, voto negativo ou simplesmente nenhuma ação.

---

PS: Esta postagem trata das minhas próprias opiniões, e não das opiniões do conjunto dos moderadores do site. Eu já debati o assunto com eles e com CMs, mas a iniciativa de abrir a discussão aqui foi individual.

Answer (score 9):

Bom, também darei minha opinião pessoal, não tenho informações privilegiadas.

Eu acho que uma reformulação desses motivos de sinalização seria bem vinda, exatamente como precisa de mais debate e a instância adequada é o metão mesmo. Nada será mudado só aqui.

Uma das mudanças poderia ser o fim desta sinalização. Não estou nem defendendo isso, mas vejo como possibilidade. Mas isso implica uma mudança de filosofia.

A frase que a descreve não bate bem com a ação que ela causa.

A descrição realmente indica que só deve ser sinalizado algo que está muito ruim e que provavelmente a ação correta é remover o conteúdo. O que na prática deve ocorrer com quase nada. No fundo ficará para spam, maluquices, coisas que na prática não são resposta, que já possui sua própria sinalização.

Porém até por dar uma negativo automático (em certas circunstâncias específicas) indica que a ideia dos criadores do mecanismo é realmente dar a chance de um moderador concordar e a resposta "afundar" mais um pouco, ou seja que ajude classificação negativa dela. Tanto que se a pergunta foi positivada, não tem efeito. Me parece um medidor de qualidade.

E se ela existe me parece que o comportamento é adequado, mesmo que não bata muito com a descrição. Ainda cabe a discussão se deveria existir. As discussões no metão também indicam isso.

Até acho interessante quando o próprio sistema sinaliza para um moderador analisar e coloca na fila para a comunidade decidir o que fazer. O Comunidade não pode negativar algo sozinho, precisa da autorização de um moderador. Também é interessante quando um usuário de baixo privilégio sinaliza. Mas pelo que comentei com o bfavaretto provavelmente só deveria deixar um usuário experiente sinalizar se ele já negativou para ele não terceirizar o "serviço sujo".

Obviamente que é possível dar uma interpretação diferente. Ainda fica aberto para outras opiniões. Pelo menos passamos ter um parâmetro melhor porque hoje vai muito no "achômetro" de cada um como lidar com isso.

Quando dão essa sinalização errada ainda dá para tratar bem. Ruim é quando marcam uma "não é uma resposta" e é, aí o moderador fica sem muita opção para fazer e muitas vezes tem que rejeitar a sinalização porque ela é inadequada, apesar de ter problemas no conteúdo.

Isto inclusive ajudará eu ver como propor algumas mudanças de inclusão de conteúdo que hoje não é aceito e poderia, desde que tenha mecanismos para proteger de conteúdo ruim. Isto já é promessa de campanha e que hoje faz 1 ano que estou enrolando pra cumprir por falta de tempo de formular algo que funcione.

Comment: Sim, o mecanismo de auto down é para marcar com votos a qualidade do post. Me incomoda justamente essa marcação ser delegada pros moderadores, quando quem sinaliza tem o privilégio de downvote. O site incentiva os usuários a tomar a ação errada e joga o problema pra moderação.

Comment: Nesse ponto concordo. Pelo menos deveria exigir que ele tivesse votado negativamente primeiro. Talvez exceção para quem não tem 125 pontos. Porque também muitas vezes a sinalização é para o moderador atuar por quem não pode.

Comment: Atuar por quem não pode é justo, concordo.

Comment: Mas e meu pontinho que eu custei pra conseguir e vou perder no downvote?

Comment: @EMBarbosa sim, claro, a regra é essa. Pode-se discutir se deveria ser.

Comment: @bigown Nahh... É uma boa regra. Eu particularmente não me lembro de ter usado a flag... Mas quero dizer que acho que perder os pontos é um dos motivos de as pessoas usarem a flag ao invés do downvote.

Answer (score 3):

Eu concordo com a pergunta, e com a resposta do Bigown.

Algumas sugestões para discutir aqui, e talvez levar aos dev's:

Para perguntas:

- Reduzir a quantidade de sinalizações disponíveis para usuários sem o privilégio de votar para fechar;
- Ainda para os usuários sem o privilégio de votar para fechar, incluir um diálogo de confirmação. Ou seja, após clicar em *"sinalizar resposta"*, o usuário veria um segundo modal dizendo algo como "**Você tem certeza?** Utilize esta opção somente se você acredita que realmente não há como melhorar a pergunta. Se a pergunta puder ser melhorada através de uma edição, é preferível que você faça isso ao invés de sinalizar".
- Para os usuários que têm o privilégio de votar para fechar, remover esse tipo de sinalização (eu testei o diálogo de sinalização e vi que tenho essa opção). Minha opinião é que se a pergunta é tão ruim que não dá para salvar, então o motivo *"não está clara o suficiente"* já dá conta do recado. Sim, eu sei que "não está claro" e "não dá para salvar" são duas coisas diferentes, mas aos meus olhos a segunda coisa é apenas uma forma mais específica da primeira.

Para respostas:

Já existe uma opção na sinalização de respostas, que diz, com ênfase minha:

> Não é uma resposta
>
> Esta resposta não é uma tentativa concreta de resolver o problema. Seria melhor transformada em comentário, edição, outra pergunta ou **excluída**.

Acho que isso já é suficiente. Para respostas a sinalização de baixa qualidade me parece desnecessária. Se é tão ruim que não dá para salvar, é para excluir mesmo.

---

Outra ideia é que essas sinalizações gerem um voto negativo automático, na hora, sem depender da moderação, e por conta de quem sinalizou e não da comunidade. Com isso:

- Usuários que não têm reputação para dar votos negativos não teriam como sinalizar. Eu acho bizarro usuários com 15-124 pontos terem o poder de disparar um processo de moderação, mas não poderem votar por conta própria;
- Quem tiver excedido o limite diário de votos não poderia sinalizar. Já fizeram trabalho suficiente para um dia;
- Haverá o custo em reputação. É um custo minúsculo e que não incomoda a maioria dos usuários... Mas o meu pensamento aqui é que, ao provocar o voto negativo, a sinalização mostraria ao usuário que ele realmente tem que estar envolvido com o que faz e que deve ser dono de suas ações.

De qualquer forma, não faz sentido você sinalizar que algo não presta, mas deixar de marcar a mesma coisa (via voto) como algo que não é útil.

Comment: Essa parte é um pouco ambígua: `Se é tão ruim que não dá para salvar, é para excluir mesmo.`, acho que se for ruim mas for uma resposta tem que negativar, não excluir, mas vc acabou dizendo isso no final da resposta: `não faz sentido você sinalizar que algo não presta, mas deixar de marcar a mesma coisa (via voto) como algo que não é útil.`, então to na dúvida se foi aquilo mesmo que vc quis dizer

Comment: @Math se uma resposta pode ser salva com edições, apenas o voto negativo é suficiente. Mas se uma resposta é tão ruim, mas tão ruim, que por mais que você edite ela nunca vai ser boa, então por que mantê-la no site?

Comment: É por isso que a sinalização de baixa qualidade causa tanta confusão, eliminando essa sinalização sobraria apenas a "não é uma resposta", que em minha opinião é quando a resposta deve ser apagada, se ela for ruim ou errada não deve ser sinalizada, mas votada contra

Comment: @Math sim. Acho que seria a melhor solução.

Comment: Por isso que eu acho que a descrição do motivo está muito errado. A SE parece ter começado um processo de melhorar muito essas coisas. Foi constituída equipe para lidar com todos os pontos pendentes, contratação de gente especializada em UX, o fim do Docs pra concentrar no Q&A, tudo isto pode ajudar começar andar esses pontos.