# O que se fazer com respostas que tem problemas de segurança?

Tags: debate

Eu queria fazer essa pergunta há muito tempo, mas vamos lá.

---

Veja [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/108366/1) de 14/01/2016, que claramente faz o que não é recomendado, por motivos de segurança, isso [é inclusive mencionado no manual](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.unserialize.php). Porém ninguém comentou ou mencionou este problema, nem mesmo fui negativado nessa resposta. Posteriormente, recentemente, [editei ela para que corrigir o problema](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/108366/3).

Mas isso ocorre várias e várias vezes em várias situações, como por exemplo [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9171/como-descobrir-quem-fez-request-em-determinado-arquivo-php/9248#9248), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/176915/15089), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/170837/15089), [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/179390/15089), tudo isso é vulnerável pelo mesmo motivo, alguns eu comentei e [disse aqui.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/222285/porque-n%C3%A3o-%C3%A9-bom-usar-essa-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-e-como-eu-identifico-o-ip-do-usu%C3%A1rio-ent%C3%A3o)

Estou fazendo essa publicação aqui após ver [esta resposta em especifica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/225715/15089), que por mim é totalmente quebrada, uma vez que o `$codigo` é justamente um `base64_encode` ou seja permite que sabendo o e-mail eu mesmo redefino a senha dele, mesmo que não tenha acesso ao respectivo e-mail. Afinal qualquer um pode fazer `base64_encode($meu_email)`. Por mim esta resposta falha miseravelmente em seu objetivo.

---

Alguns dias atrás eu vi essa [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/224874/15089), que me deixou um pouco grilado. O motivo é que o autor da pergunta utilizou `/^[0-9]{9,11,13}$`, note os `^ e $` enquanto a resposta aceita não, resolvi investigar um pouco isso. Cheguei a encontrar uma [lista de vulnerabilidades/erros](https://github.com/attackercan/regexp-security-cheatsheet) que podem ser cometidos no REGEX e juro que nunca tinha me dado conta dessas situações, nunca nem tinha ouvido falar de ReDoS por exemplo. A resposta (inclusive aceita pelo OP) faz com que `00000-0000;<script>alert()</script>` seja um telefone válido. Isso seria um problema de segurança?!

Existem outros casos, que já vi por aí no site, que acredito que seja mais obscuro e que realmente podem ser ignorados em casos gerais ou dependem muito da aplicação, do contexto. Alguns casos acho que é aceitável como por exemplo comparar CSRF-Token usando `===` (ao invés de `hash_equals()` que seria o ideal). Alguns casos acredito que seja pouco conhecido e mais especifico como usar `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` e não especificar o `CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS` quando se utilizar cURL, [até corrigi algumas respostas minhas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/179199/4) algum tempo atrás, ou usar `OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING` como padding (ao invés de usar `OPENSSL_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING`), acredito difícil alguém notar estes problemas numa resposta por serem especificas.

Mas claro, isso é só um exemplo e obviamente estou longe de saber de todos os problemas que podem existir, tanto que até alguns dias atrás fazia REGEX totalmente errados.

A questão é justamente essa. Deve haver várias e várias respostas que deve estar cheias de problemas, mas ninguém parece ligar para isso e o autor das respostas/perguntas continuam sem saber que aquilo é um erro (ou que possui um problema iminente de segurança). E pior, as vezes tem votos positivos e é aceita como melhor resposta.

Acho estranho, uma melhor resposta, [como essa minha, mencionada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/108366/1), é justamente a resposta que é insegura (a outra não tinha nenhum problema).

---

Queria saber de vocês, em geral do StackOverflow: **O que fazer?**

Ignorar e presumir que quem for utilizar aquele código já sabe de todo o seu comportamento e que não há problema algum nisso? Editar as perguntas para que corrija o problema quando possível? Negativar a respostas? Comentar o problema?

Eu "frequentemente" vejo alguns usuários comentando nas perguntas (ou até nas respostas) que o código "[está vulnerável a MySQL Injection](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/218419/parse-error-no-c%C3%B3digo/218423#comment447056_218419)" por exemplo, acho que isso algo positivo. Acredito que com este "alerta" serve para pessoa reconhecer o problema e talvez corrigir. Mas, não vejo isso sendo feito em outros casos.

Ultimamente tento comentar quando vejo algum problema da resposta/pergunta ou as vezes respondo de alguma outra forma e menciono porque ela seria melhor. Mas não sei se isso é algo bom de ser feito e se é bem recebido, porque acredito que ninguém liga.

Comment: Acredito que o melhor sempre é presumir que quem respondeu desconhece tal problema com a segurança e comentar alertando, possivelmente criando outra resposta resolvendo o problema.

Comment: Obrigado pelo toque sobre segurança com regex. Pode comentar nas respostas mesmo, isso é bastante útil.

Comment: Não entendi como a expressão vulnerável, poderia permitir a injeção do script... Fiz um teste com o `pattern` do `html5` e ele não válida a injeção, pode dizer algo a respeito?

Comment: Cross posts: [meta soen](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303065)
  [meta soen2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/293930) 
  [metao](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158741)

Answer (score 11):

Se o conteúdo é seu, melhore.

Se é de outro:

- comente para o autor melhorar
- deixe claro para quem for ele que há problemas ali
- se está errado mesmo, não é só um detalhe desimportante, provavelmente deve negativar a resposta
- quem sabe seja o caso de [sinalizar como baixa qualidade](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6225/101)
- faça uma resposta melhor para os leitores terem uma alternativa
- se for muito importante quem sabe seja o caso de mostrar isso no [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha).

Em geral não acho bom mudar a intenção do autor, mesmo que ela seja errada.

Se o problema for muito pequeno dá para ignorar. Bom, dá para ignorar sempre, ninguém é obrigado fazer algo no site, mas estou entendendo que a pergunta se refere a quem quer contribuir positivamente.

> código usa mysql_* ou que está vulnerável a MySQL Injection

Isto não é uma verdade tão absoluta assim, mas não vem ao caso aqui.

Comment: Eu concordo com quase tudo (+1). A única coisa que não entendi é "sinalizar como baixa qualidade". Pelo post linkado, a sinalização de "baixa qualidade" **atualmente** não corresponde ao sentido mais amplo. Então acho dispensável fazer isso. É preferível comentar e negativar.

Answer (score 2):

Eu entendo sua preocupação. Porém em muitos casos a necessidade de uma solução paliativa é tão grande, que o desenvolvedor prefere resolver o problema mesmo com falhas de segurança.
Fora que não tem como corrigir o problema das respostas de todo mundo. Isso cabe à comunidade. As vezes o autor da resposta não faz a mínima ideia que a solução que ele está propondo tem falhas na segurança.

Comment: *"Fora que não tem como corrigir o problema das respostas de todo mundo. Isso cabe à comunidade."*... ué... ele não é parte da comunidade? Então cabe a ele também.

Comment: Concordo plenamente!