# Porque esta sinalização foi rejeitada?

Tags: debate, sinalização

Eu fiz uma sinalização a alguns dias atrás para [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/54020/66203), e vi hoje que ela foi rejeitada com o seguinte motivo:

> rejeitado - um moderador revisou sua sinalização, mas não achou evidência que a confirme.

Como assim? Eu sinalizei porque respostas semelhantes a essa:

> Método estático não precisa do objeto para ser acessado, é uma das funções se não me engano...

Me parecem um comentário e (ao meu ponto de vista) totalmente inclusa neste motivo de sinalização:

> Esta resposta não é uma tentativa concreta de resolver o problema. **Seria melhor transformada em comentário**, edição, outra pergunta ou excluída.

Além disso "*para ajudar*", o usuário não tem pontos de reputação o suficiente, o que aumenta o indício dele de querer ajudar, mas por não ter pontos suficientes, fez uma resposta comentário.

Então, o que aconteceu? Eu estou errado, fiz uma sinalização incorreta? Esse tipo de resposta está sendo aceita? Ou ocorreu um erro na hora da análise da sinalização por parte do moderador?

Comment: É uma resposta válida e ainda está certa. É ruim (**beeeem** ruim, mas ainda assim é válida), mesmo que tivesse errada, seria válida, então acho que foi por isso que foi recusada.

Comment: Bota + ruim nisso @LINQ. Mas mesmo assim, ainda acho que está no formato de um comentário.

Comment: Um exemplo de caso parecido é [esta resposta aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/204524/18246). Está completamente errada e não resolve o problema, mas não vai ser apagada porque é uma "tentativa de responder a pergunta". O pior de tudo é que o cabra ainda ganhou 3 votos numa resposta sem sentido.

Comment: O motivo é o extremo oposto. Não é que essa resposta pareca um comentário, é que muita gente costuma comentar respondendo a questão, por medo de perder pontos com uma resposta simples talvez.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Fui eu quem rejeitou desta vez, outras vezes a mesma resposta foi sinalizada pelo mesmo motivo e foi rejeitada por outros moderadores.

Se a sinalização fosse de baixa qualidade provavelmente seria aceita já que a resposta é mesmo de baixa qualidade.

Mas ela é uma resposta, apesar de ruim. Só porque é curto não quer dizer que seja um comentário.

Nem sempre é fácil analisar esses casos que triscam a linha de uma coisa ou outra. Tem que tentar analisar a intenção. Temos que fazer o possível para que a resposta seja válida, e só quando realmente não chega responder nada é que deve ser um comentário.

Note que estar errada não invalida como uma resposta, respostas erradas ainda são respostas :)

Comment: Parece até que eu já sabia, achei mesmo que fosse você. Apesar de ser contra deixar aquela resposta eu compreendi o motivo da sinalização rejeitada: `"respostas erradas ainda são respostas :)"`

Comment: E ela nem está errada, só muito fraca.

Comment: Aproveitando o pulo: "*Se a sinalização fosse de baixa qualidade provavelmente seria aceita*", eu sempre tive dúvidas nisso, pois a descrição da sinalização de baixa qualidade é "*tão ruim que uma edição não basta e deve ser removida*", porém na sinalização de não-resposta há "*Seria melhor transformada em ... edição*", dando a entender que uma edição salvaria. Com base nisso eu sempre votei como não-resposta aquelas que eu achava que podiam ser melhoradas com uma edição.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss essas descrições estão ruins e estão sendo discutidas em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6225/101. O problema é que se a edição salva e não é uma resposta, o que já me parece uma contradição, o moderador deve fazer o que? Se ele não conseguir salvar por conta própria, deve fazer nada? O moderador deve ficar sobrecarregado de tentar salvar essas respostas?

Comment: Posso estar errado mas ao sinalizar não aparece a opção de resposta de "baixa qualidade", apenas aparece "não é uma resposta"

Comment: @ramaral provavelmente porque isto já foi processado uma vez.

Comment: @ramaral, foi exatamente essa o motivo de usar essa sinalização. Não aparecia o "baixa qualidade", e apesar de válida o formato se assemelhava a um comentário.

Comment: @ramaral O que quer dizer com "processado"?

Comment: Já foi tratado, já foi inspecionado, já aconteceu antes.

Comment: Então, se assim é, agora também não deveria aparecer "não é uma resposta", já que foi processado(rejeitado) por si.

Comment: @ramaral concordo, porém tem um monte de inconsistências no sistema, tem coisas que não dá para entender.