# O que se passou aqui?

Tags: debate, sinalização

Sinalizei uma [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/220551/arrendondamento-com-formatfloat/220665#220665) como "não é uma resposta" a qual foi rejeitada, na pergunta é dito o seguinte:

> Ao tentar arredondar para 4 casas decimais o valor 18,36735 por meio
>   da função FormatFloat, o sistema gera o valor 18,3673. Como isso é
>   possível?

A resposta diz:

> É um comportamento normal. O arredondamento segue uma métrica, até 4
>   arredonda para baixo. A partir do 5 arredondo para cima.

Penso que na realidade não é uma resposta porque a pergunta diz que não está a fazer bem os arredondamentos, e a resposta diz que é um comportamento normal.

Estarei eu a fazer uma má analise a pergunta e resposta ou a minha sinalização foi mal rejeitada?

**EDIT1:**

Só para não estar a fazer outra pergunta e como é um assunto relacionado pergunto também já agora o porque disto, sinalizei uma outra resposta deixo uma imagem: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Foi rejeitada mas no entanto a alteração foi feita, passaram a resposta para a [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/220848/como-localizar-e-abrir-arquivo-txt-acrescentar-informa%C3%A7%C3%B5es-e-salvar-dentro-do). O que poderá ter acontecido aqui?

Comment: Só que precisa de 5 pessoas com menos de 20k e/ou 3 com mais de 20k (para remover caso o post esteja com certo numero de negativos) concordando com você para que a sinalização seja aceita. Isso se chama  "decidir em comunidade".

Comment: Vou simplesmente comentar, por que já [aconteceu comigo](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6329/66203). É uma tentativa de responder a pergunta, é uma resposta válida. **É ruim (beeeem ruim, mas ainda assim é válida)**, ela é uma resposta, apesar de ruim. Respostas erradas ainda são respostas. Se a sinalização fosse de baixa qualidade, poderia se fazer alguma coisa, mas como foi não é resposta, nada a se fazer.

Comment: @Articuno concordo mas gostava de intender se eu estou a ter um mau raciocínio, ou pelo contrário

Comment: @Stormwind obrigado acho que percebi a ideia

Comment: Qual opção você sinalizou agora?

Comment: @Stormwind "Precisa da atenção dos moderadores" deveria ter escolhido "não é uma resposta"?

Comment: Sim, utilize a sinalização adequada para os casos adequados @Tmc. Nesse caso não é uma resposta seria mais adequado. Escolhendo outras variantes, você está "*tirando*" a atenção do moderador de algo mais importante, enquanto ele poderia estar lidando com algo mais sério.

Comment: @Stormwind obrigado por tudo, é com os erros que crescemos

Answer (score 9, accepted):

É uma resposta fraca, porém correta, mas é uma resposta, por isso precisa sinalizar corretamente, se fosse baixa qualidade algo poderia ser feito.

Comment: então quer dizer que a resposta esta incorreta mas continua a ser uma resposta... é isso?

Comment: Eu acho ela correta, só muito fraca, mas é uma resposta. Sei que a linha muitas vezes é tênue, mas neste caso achei que respondia alguma coisa. Clar oque eu sempre posso estar enganado.

Comment: @Manieiro Responder responde sem dúvida apesar de não ser a resposta desejada pelo perguntante... como referi em outro comentário é com os erros que aprendemos

Comment: Nem sempre dá para responder o que a pessoa deseja, pelo menos de forma correta. Claro que foi minha interpretação, sempre é debatível.

Answer (score 2):

Ia ser comentários, mas já fiz muitos...

> Estarei eu a fazer uma má analise a pergunta e resposta ou a minha sinalização foi mal rejeitada?

Esse seu caso é muito parecido com um outro,  [Porque esta sinalização foi rejeitada?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6329/66203). Nela eu pergunto de uma sinalização semelhante a sua.

Descobri que o motivo é que a resposta **é uma tentativa de responder a pergunta**, é uma resposta válida. É ruim (**bem ruim, mas ainda assim é válida**), e apesar de ruim, ela é uma resposta. Respostas erradas ainda são respostas.

> Se a sinalização fosse de baixa qualidade provavelmente seria aceita já que a resposta é mesmo de baixa qualidade. **Mas ela é uma resposta, apesar de ruim**.

E como você fez uma de não é uma resposta, ela não foi aceita (e nem deve ser), já que é o motivo selecionado é incorreto, então nada a se fazer.

---

Sobre a outra sinalização rejeitada, é importante que você utilize a sinalização mais adequada para os diversos casos. Nesse caso, marcar como não é uma resposta seria mais adequado.

Escolhendo as outras variantes, você está "tirando" a atenção do moderador de algo mais importante, e enquanto ele poderia estar lidando com algo mais sério, ele está lá, resolvendo algum *pepino menor* que usuários com privilégio de serem "confiáveis" já resolveriam sem problemas.

Answer (score 1):

Eu pessoalmente penso que a resposta **não** está inteiramente correta, sim eu concordo que é uma tentativa de responder, portanto é uma **resposta** e a sinalização não foi correta ali, mas a resposta ainda sim está parcialmente errada.

Não sou *expert* em matemática e nem em questões que envolvem isto em computadores, mas quero lhes alertar sobre um detalhe, o autor da resposta fala:

> ... até 4 arredonda para baixo. A partir do 5 arredondo para cima.

Isso claro em um teste simples é correto, mas o problema não é este a questão do arredondamento creio eu é a *"precisão"* do *"ponto fixo"*, para ser mais claro segue um exemplo em JavaScript:

A partir de 5 o resultado ainda é `18.3673`:

```js
console.log(18.36735.toFixed(4))
```

Se fosse `50` (uma posição a mais nos decimais) o resultado ainda é `18.3673`:

```js
console.log(18.367350.toFixed(4))
```

Agora observem se for `51` o resultado é `18.3674`:

```js
console.log(18.367351.toFixed(4))
```

Então penso que a sinalização ali não foi o caminho ideal, mas talvez sim fornecer uma resposta mais apropriada.